# Why my routerLink is not showing my CalendarComponent

Tags: angular

I have an app hooked up with a backend. Whenever I run the project and then press ng serve, everything works as planned. I can even see the routerlink that i created and when I hover the mouse over the link it shows the correct path- localhost:4200/Calendar

When clicked however, it renders the Sunday through Saturday top box only with no dates or nothing. I get this in the console though:

"Error TypeError: Cannot CalendarComponent.html:12 read property 'getMonth' of undefined at CalendarComponent.dateStyle (calendar.component.ts:66)

Whenever I boot up just the calendar component by itself into an app.component.html, it shows the full calendar fine. So I am wondering why I am shown a type error here with a backend, and not with just the frontend which successfully shows the calendar?

Relevant Code: 
calendar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.scss']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  currentDate = new Date();
  months : string[] = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  days: string[] = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  monthToDisplay: string;
  currentYear : number; 
  weeks2 = [];


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getYear();
    this.setDate();
    this.getMonth();
  }

  getMonth() {
     this.monthToDisplay = this.months[this.weeks2[1][0].getMonth()];
  }

  getFirstDay() {
    return this.days[this.currentDate.getDay()];
  }

  getYear() {
    this.currentYear =  this.currentDate.getFullYear();
  }

  setDate() {
    let previousSunday = new Date('2019, 11, 10');


    while(previousSunday.getDate() != 1) {
      previousSunday = new Date(previousSunday.getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }


    while(previousSunday.getDay() != 0) {
      previousSunday = new Date(previousSunday.getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }
  console.log(previousSunday);

    let temp = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
      let d = this.setDay(previousSunday, i);
      temp.push(d);
      if(temp.length == 7) {
        this.weeks2.push(temp);
        temp = [];
      }
    }

}

  setDay(day: Date, i: number) {
    return new Date(day.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * i);
  }

  dateStyle(day: Date) {
    if(day.getMonth() == this.weeks2[1][0].getMonth()) {
      return 'amGreen';
   }
      return 'amRed';
}

clickMe(day: Date) {
  console.log( day + 'has been clicked!');
}

}
```

calendar.component.html

```
<h3>{{ monthToDisplay }} {{ currentYear }}</h3>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let day of days">
                 {{ day }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let week of weeks2">
            <td *ngFor="let weekDay of week" [ngClass]="dateStyle(weekDay)" (click)="clickMe(weekDay)">
                {{ weekDay.getDate() }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are u sure **weeks2** array is filled properly ?

Comment: I believe it is, if you look in my for loop i assign weeks2 values. I just commented out the [ngClass] and it works so the weeks2 must have properly filled values in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, it sounds like it's failing when it tries to get the class for the individual row.

```html
[ngClass]="dateStyle(weekDay)"
```

This in turn causes it to call the dateStyle method which contains this code.

```
if(day.getMonth() == this.weeks2[1][0].getMonth()) {
```

This means that this.weeks2[1][0] is undefined.

Try changing it to this:

```
if (day && this.weeks2 && this.weeks2.length >= 2 && this.weeks2[1] &&  
  this.weeks2[1].length >= 1 && day.getMonth() == this.weeks2[1][0].getMonth())
```

I realize that's a bit of a mouthful, but it does all the null/undefined checks that would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out in my ngClass dateStyle parameter, i had weekday and not weekDay. That solved the problem!